# using wcscpy to copy a string

Tags: c, string

I was experimenting with `wchar_t` and I tried to copy one array into another array.
here is my code:

```
wchar_t name[]=L"Aayman Khalid";
wchar_t Name[50]=L"";
wcscpy_s(Name,sizeof(name),name);
printf_s( "Name = %s\n", Name );
```

however when I run this code,I get the first letter i.e `A`.
could someone explain to me as to why that is?
Also how could I get the full name copied?

Comment: note also that wcscpy_s takes *number of elements*, not number of bytes as second argument.

Comment: @ claptrap,which means that I have to give the number of elements of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf_s` with `"%ls"` specifier.

Comment: @ DuXeN0N,Thanks it worked:),could you explain it to me a little bit?

Comment: wchar_t is a 16 bit character type, and for the letter A, for example, the first byte is 65, and the second byte is zero. For printf, the %s format expects strings terminated by a null character, ie. zero, therefore it stops after displaying the first byte. %ls expects 16-byte characters, therefore will stop when meeting two zero's as terminating character.

Comment: @AaymanKhalid, wchar_t is two byte encoding character. As your name[] contains only ASCII letters second byte of each char is zero. printf() with %s spec. prints characters until it sees null-terminating byte. So, to let printf know that your string is two byte encoded you should use %ls.

Comment: alt. use `wprintf` and `%s`